# Передача функции в андроид

Tags: android, kotlin, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста,у меня есть класс NewsViewModel в котором происходит вся работа, в нем есть функция fun creathNewsModel()

```
fun creathNewsModel() {

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {


            val response: Response<NewsJson> = RetofitInst.api.getNews().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                var data: NewsJson = response.body()!!
                //заполнение даныvb Активити
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    data_1.text = data.news[0].date
                    news_1.text = data.news[0].description

                    data_2.text = data.news[1].date
                    news_2.text = data.news[1].description

                    data_3.text = data.news[2].date
                    news_3.text = data.news[2].description

                    data_4.text = data.news[3].date
                    news_4.text = data.news[3].description

                    data_5.text = data.news[4].date
                    news_5.text = data.news[4].description

                    DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(data)
                    data_6.text = data.news[5].date
                    news_6.text = data.news[5].description
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Произошла ошибка...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        }
```

Как мне вызвать эту функцию в MainActivity? думал как то так(NewsViewModel().creathNewsModel()) но выкидывает ошибку когда запускаешь приложение на телефоне

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        NewsViewModel().creathNewsModel()

    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите какую ошибку и на какой строчке выкидывает

Comment: Если у вас NewsViewModel унаследован от ViewModel то конечно так не будет вызываться, вот так вот надо viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NewsViewModel ::class.java); viewModel.creathNewsModel()